# Why 1.01 equals -0.75 in Q2

Tags: conversion

I'm trying to learn Q notation but I don't understand why 1.01 in the Q2 number format equals -0.75. How is that calculation done? I can understand that 1.1 equals -0.5 because the leading 1 means the number is negative and the first digit after the binary point is 1 which means 1*2^(-1) which is 0.5 and therefore the number is -0.5. Similarly, 1.01 should equal -0.25 and not -0.75.

It is 1.11 which is -0.75 or what is my mistake?

Comment: What do you mean by Q2? I am only familiar with Qm.n format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)

Comment: @AtulIngle : that page says *m. (optional, assumed to be zero or one)* so I'm assuming the format is Q1.2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$1\times (-1)+0\times2^{-1}+1\times2^{-2}=-0.75$$